# SQLite with Slick and Play

Tags: scala, sqlite, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

So I'm trying to modify one of the typesafe activator templates to use an SQLite database instead of the built in H2 one. Here is the original template https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/templates/play-scala-intro

What I've done is to change the application.conf file to have these lines:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver=slick.driver.SQLiteDriver
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcin/play-scala-intro/people.db"
```

Of course I also created the file itself (just did `touch people.db`). Then if I start my application I am getting the following error:

```
[info] ! @6ooe822f0 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
[info]  
[info] play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
[info]  at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
[info]  at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
[info]  at play.api.db.slick.DefaultSlickApi$DatabaseConfigFactory.create(SlickApi.scala:93) ~[play-slick_2.11-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
[info]  at play.api.db.slick.DefaultSlickApi$DatabaseConfigFactory.get$lzycompute(SlickApi.scala:81) ~[play-slick_2.11-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
[info]  at play.api.db.slick.DefaultSlickApi$DatabaseConfigFactory.get(SlickApi.scala:80) ~[play-slick_2.11-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
```

I was looking for some examples how to set it up like here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaquery/07JBbnZ5VZk/7D1_5N4uGjsJ

or here:

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick

but they weren't similar enough to my code and since I'm new to all this I couldn't really figure out how to use them. Help appreciated, thanks!

**[EDIT]:**

following a suggestion from the comment I added "$" at the end of the driver name, to that what's in the conf file now looks like this:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver=slick.driver.SQLiteDriver$
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcin/play-scala-intro/people.db"
```

That works in the sense that another error comes up:

```
[info] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured 
[info] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:441) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na] 
[info] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na] 
[info] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Change `slick.driver.SQLiteDriver` to `slick.driver.SQLiteDriver$`. If this does not help, please add the root cause of your stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It did help in the sense that now I'm getting a different error `[info] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured
[info]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:441) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
[info]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
`

Comment: Maybe setting a test query in your `applicaion.conf` helps: `slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="select 1" `.

Comment: Off-topic: On SO it is common to edit questions with new findings instead of adding them in comments. This way it is much easier for other users to help you solving the problem :)

Comment: Alright, I think I'm giving up on it now. Your suggestions helped but I'm having other problems and it is not really an essential part of the project right now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is quite old question, but maybe the answer can be useful for someone.

All the works is based upon the example presented here: 
https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-samples-play-scala-slick-example

I've successfully run SQLite database with Scala/Play/Slick performing the following steps:

1. build.sbt file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := """Application""",
    version := "2.8.x",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.1",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      guice,
      "org.playframework.anorm" %% "anorm"                 % "2.6.5",
      "com.typesafe.play"       %% "play-slick"            % "5.0.0",
      "com.typesafe.play"       %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "5.0.0",
      "org.xerial"              %  "sqlite-jdbc"           % "3.31.1",
      specs2 % Test,
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-feature",
      "-deprecation",
      "-Xfatal-warnings"
    )
  )
```

2. application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.profile="slick.driver.SQLiteDriver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:sqlite:/mnt/comments.db"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Please note, that it also works in the case for the relative path:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.profile="slick.driver.SQLiteDriver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:sqlite:./comments.db"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Play Evolution also works:

```
play.evolutions {
  db.default.enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have play, slick, SQLite project: https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb

It also has a repository pattern.

Please check out https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb/releases/tag/v0.0.5

To give an example of how slick works with SQLite:

```
import slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile.api._ // must import
lazy val db = Database.forURL(url = AbsoluteDatabasePath)
```

Repository pattern for slick
https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb/tree/6bf6beb6adb93b83cba49085d2d33269502189e1/app/shared/com/repository

You may download the repo in that release and run it using SBT

```
 run sbt
```

or open using IntelliJ IDEA

Routers example of Play (https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb/blob/6bf6beb6adb93b83cba49085d2d33269502189e1/app/controllers/controllerRoutes/routerGeneric/RtbServiceBasicRouter.scala)

```
class RtbServiceBasicRouter @Inject()(
  controller : RequestSimulatorServiceApiController)
  extends SimpleRouter {

  val routingActionWrapper : ControllerGenericActionWrapper = ControllerGenericActionWrapper(
    ControllerDefaultActionType.Routing)

  override def routes : Routes = {
    try {
      case GET(p"/serviceName") | GET(p"/") =>
        controller.getServiceName()

      case GET(p"/commands") | GET(p"/available-commands") | GET(p"/routes") =>
        controller.getAvailableCommands()
      case GET(p"/bannerRequest") =>
        controller.getBannerRequestSample()
    } catch {
      case e : Exception =>
        controller.handleError(e, routingActionWrapper)
        throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Add routes controller to the routes (https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb/blob/6bf6beb6adb93b83cba49085d2d33269502189e1/conf/routes)

```
->         /services/v1/rtbSimulateService                  controllers.controllerRoutes.routerGeneric.RtbServiceBasicRouter
```

SBT Packages:
https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb/blob/6bf6beb6adb93b83cba49085d2d33269502189e1/build.sbt

Recommended packages for Sqlite in SBT:

```
  "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "2.2.1", // for time convert
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "2.4.2", // 2.4 doesn't work
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.30.1", // sqlite driver
```

Slick Packages if you want to integrate :

```
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.3.2", // for generating Table schema for sqlite db
```

Example for sqlite db to Table Schema generate (Database First Approach) [https://github.com/aukgit/scala-open-real-time-bidding-rtb/blob/6bf6beb6adb93b83cba49085d2d33269502189e1/app/shared/com/ortb/executors/DatabaseEngineCodeGenerator.scala] :

```
slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.run(
    profile = databaseGenerateConfig.profile,// "slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile",
    jdbcDriver = databaseGenerateConfig.jdbcDriver, //"org.sqlite.JDBC",
    url = databaseGenerateConfig.compiledDatabaseUrl, //
    // "jdbc:sqlite:D:\\PersonalWork\\Github\\scala-rtb-example\\src\\main\\resources\\openRTBSample.db",
    outputDir = databaseGenerateConfig.compiledOutputDir, //
    // "D:\\PersonalWork\\Github\\scala-rtb-example\\src\\main\\scala\\com\\ortb\\persistent\\schema",
    pkg = databaseGenerateConfig.pkg,
    user = None,
    password = None,
    ignoreInvalidDefaults = true,
    outputToMultipleFiles = false
    )
```